# Created a new customer group and shipping rates have changed.

Tags: shipping, shipping-tax

So like the title says, I've created a new customer group and everyone in that customer group automatically has different shipping rates.

[image]

Our typical "home delivery" price for every customer is $9.99. Why all of a sudden is the customers in this new group displaying $11.19?

I noticed it's on a product price basis, if i add more stuff to the cart it goes up more.

I've looked through admin but nothing is jumping out at me thats changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will discover what's going on with your shipping rules here in admin: Sales > Shipping Rules.

Inside here you will see your active rules or you will be able to "add rule".

More than likely you have a general rule in place. Click inside that rule if you do have a default one setup. The subsidary menu on the left hand side should say Stores & Customer Groups, click on that tab and find "Apply For" and select your new user group there.

Comment: That appears to be what I'm looking for, thank you.